# Merge Java Web Applications

Tags: java, merge

I am new to java development, I am supposed to merge two java applications, first one is OpenCMS and second one is an old core java (Servlets and JSPs) based application (also it has many other technologies like struts, JSF and Hibernate etc.) I need some basic idea regarding this.

Comment: What do you mean by *merge*? This is by no means a trivial exercise, if you are going to clump the sources of both and pray that they work. Perhaps you mean integrating both to be used via a portal, or something else? Care to clarify.

Comment: Merge in what way, make them interact or a totalt codemerge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figure out the functionality missing in one, and re-implement it.  It is far easier to keep a consistent core set of practices on how it's done in one than to make a beast which marches to the beat of two out-of-sync drummers.